# How to jar a Java program for Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am going through Chapter 2 of Hadoop: The Definitive Guide 4e.

The book tells me to do the following steps:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hadoop-examples.jar
hadoop MaxTemperature input/ncdc/sample.txt output
```

What is hadoop-examples.jar? How do I jar MaxTemperature?

The code is available here: https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch02-mr-intro/src/main/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In border of my school studies we did nearly the same.

You just have to compile it directly into a jar file. 
So you can use it easier from command line or hadoop.
Otherwise you would need to compile it with

```
javac filename1.java filename2.java
```

and go on, also with all the libraries.

I guess you use something like Eclipse as IDE. There you can compile it directly into a jar file.

```
Export > Java > Runnable JAR file
```

Then you can use it in command line like this:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

or put it into the hadoop cluster.

mfg

Comment: I was able to get this working by creating runnable JARs using Eclipse. I also had to run `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=MaxTemperature.jar` before running `hadoop MaxTemperature ../input/ncdc/sample.txt output`